# Is it possible to define a new operator in Raku and control its precedence?

Tags: operators, operator-precedence, raku, rakudo

Consider this new operator:

```
sub infix:<*++>(\num1, \num2) {
    num1 * num2 + 1
}

say (2 + 1 *++ 3);
```

This code prints:

```
10
```

However, is it possible to control the precedence? Such it behaves like this:

```
say (2 + (1 *++ 3))
```

without needing to use parentheses

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible by [`is tighter`](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#index-entry-is_tighter)

```
sub infix:<*++> (\num1, \num2) is tighter(&[+])  {
      num1 * num2 + 1
}
```

Comment: Or `is equiv` or `is looser`.   Perhaps `is equiv(&[*])` is the most appropriate here.

Comment: Yes, I finally end up using is equiv :). Thanks!